# iOS Assign sound for local notification from directory

Tags: ios

Im trying to assign custom sound for local notification from data container  not from main bundle . I copied a file from bundle to Library/Sounds directory and assigned name of file  to local notification sound name property , but it does not work and keeps playing default one.

File path from Library/Sounds directory : 
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/37FA5D9B-F603-44CE-B386-DAB9D614ED68/Library/Sounds/notification.caf

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got this to work after restarting device . It sounds like it stops working if user kills the App by force quitting it from App switcher.

Comment: Can it possible to download sound from weburl in document directory and use for local notification sound

Comment: @ArvindKumar No downloading to documents directory won't work, according to Apple documentation downloading to library/sounds directly only works . If you have any further questions you're so welcome.

Comment: Thanks Bro,Its works I have just downloaded .caf file in library/sounds and use the file name with extension in Local notification sound name.

Comment: @ArvindKumar Most welcome bro , glad that it works with you , by the way other extensions work as well not only .caf , enjoy.